# Join two tables when one field is an array of Ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

EMPLOYEE

```
Name | DepartmentId | Address | Phone number
--------------------------------------------
Tom  | [a1, b2] | 51 Rue Fort  | 123456
Ron  | [a1]    | San Picafort | 234566
Matt | [b2]    | Frank Road   | 523422
```

DEPARTMENT

```
Id | Dept Name | Number of Employees | Location 
------------------------------------------
a1  | HR | 500 | Zambia
b2  | IT | 300 | Tanzania
```

I need to join two tables on DepartmentId, but the problem is DepartmentId in EMPLOYEE table is an array. I cannot run join on it. Like:

```
select *
from EMPLOYEE,
     DEPARTMENT
where EMPLOYEE.DepartmentId = DEPARTMENT.id;
```

Which will give output like:

```
Name | DepartmentId | Address | Phone number | Dept Name | Number of Employees | Location 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Tom | a1 | 51 Rue Fort | 123456 | HR | 500 | Zambia
Tom | b2 | 51 Rue Fort | 123456 | IT | 300 | Tanzania
Ron | a1 | San Picafort | 234566 | HR | 500 | Zambia
Matt | b2 | Frank Road | 523422 | IT | 300 | Tanzania
```

How can I make EMPLOYEE table atomic using a query and then run a join query?

Comment: Never ever store data as comma separated items. Your DepartmentId column will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: I got data from a NOSQL DB like this, I can't help it. Data is not normalized there.

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays.  You have a string, formatted as a JSON array.  That is not the same thing.  You should be using a junction table instead of ids formatted as a string.  You should put your efforts into fixing the data model.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are difficult to deal with and I am unsure whether @mkRabbani has the faster solution with `LIKE` but an alternative that may be better suited is a join using [FIND_IN_SET()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp).  Both are extremely inefficient, but the query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D
    ON FIND_IN_SET(D.Id, E.DepartmentId)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner approach could be having an extra table representing the many-to-many relationship between `EMPLOYEE` and `DEPARTMENT`. Let's say `EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT`. With one row for every relationship between an employer and a department. Of course, you can also add an ID to the employee table. I think all queries will be different but with a way better performance.

The tables will be like this:

EMPLOYEE

```
Id | Name | Address     | Phone number
-----------------------------------
1 | Tom  | 51 Rue Fort  | 123456
2 | Ron  | San Picafort | 234566
3 | Matt | Frank Road   | 523422
```

DEPARTMENT

```
Id | DeptName | Number of Employees | Location 
-----------------------------------------------
a1  | HR      | 500                 | Zambia
b2  | IT      | 300                 | Tanzania
```

EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT

```
Emp | Dept 
-----------
1  | a1
1  | b2
2  | a1 
3  | b2
```

The query you're asking about could be:

```
Select E.*, D.Id from EMPLOYEE as E left join EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT as ED on E.Id=ED.Emp left join DEPARTMENT as D on ED.Dept=D.Id;
```

Producing output:

```
Id | Name | Address     | Phone number | Dept Name | Number of Employees | Location | DepartmentId  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Tom   | 51 Rue Fort | 123456       | HR        | 500                 | Zambia   | a1  
1  | Tom   | 51 Rue Fort | 123456       | IT        | 300                 | Tanzania | b2 
2  | Ron   | San Picafort| 234566       | HR        | 500                 | Zambia   | a1
3  | Matt  | Frank Road  | 523422       | IT        | 300                 | Tanzania | b2
```

Also on the output you can change `DepartmentId` with other columns of `DEPARTMENT` table.

Answer (score 0):

Create the inner join with LIKE operator

```
SELECT E.NAME,
E.DepartmentId,
E.Address,
E.[Phone number],
D.[Dept Name],
D.[Number of Employees],
D.Location 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D
    ON CAST(E.DepartmentId AS VARCHER(MAX)) LIKE '%' + CAST(D.id AS VARCHER(MAX))+ '%'
```

Comment: Giving SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:31: '+' cannot be applied to varchar(1), varchar

Comment: What is data type of column E.DepartmentId and D.id?

Comment: @Bharthan - I have added CAST in both column. This should work now.